# With...as...as...its

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I think it sounds a little weird. Here's an example:

> I looked at the owl. With eyes as big as **its**, it'd definitely seen the man.

Strangely this sound OK:

> I looked at the kitty. With eyes as big as **hers**, she'd definitely seen the man.

Is the construction *with...as...as...its* grammatical? Does it sound strange? If so, what's a better alternative?

Comment: With eyes that big, it had definitely seen..."

Comment: But for me an assumption can't lead to a definitive conclusion:  "With eye that big, she surely must have seen the man."

Comment: Yeah, it sounds a hair weird.  But owls are weird anyway, so it fits.

Comment: I think some of the weirdness comes from the fact that *its* and *it's* are homophones, in addition to the proximity of *it'd*. I like @Jim's suggestion, or possibly: "With its big eyes, it had definitely…".

Comment: the former is - offbeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's because *its* is not commonly usually used as a pronoun. In contrast,  *his* is.

In the *Oxford Dictionaries Online*, *[his](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/his)* is listed as both a possessive determiner and as a stand alone possessive pronoun. However, *[its](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/its)* is only listed as a possessive determiner.

However, *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/its)* English version also limits *its* to a determiner, but its [American version](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/its?) lists both pronoun and determiner.

Several other dictionaries consulted, such as *[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=its)*, limit *its* to adjectival or determiner use, but a few do list it as a pronoun.

The other possessive pronouns differ from their possessive determiner forms:

> - hers/her
> - theirs/their
> - mine/my
> - yours/your
> - ours/our

In sum, it's technically correct, but a bit off sounding because it's uncommon.